# How do you get the content of a file revision in Google Drive SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

I'm attempting to get revision histories for google drive (actually, docs) files using the Google Drive .NET SDK. I can get the metadata for a list of revisions for a given file just fine, but it appears that for any given Revision, the DownLoadUrl field is always null, and the ExportLinks all point back to the most recent complete version of the doc (i.e., not to the revision indicated by the metadata).

Any suggestions? Is this just how it works? I've noticed that the return value in the API explorer for the Revision object behaves in the same way.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The `downloadUrl` field is only populated on files with content stored in Drive and not for Google native formats.

Please edit your question to add the file metadata if the API is still not behaving as expected.

Comment: Ok, but what about the ExportLinks? They don't link to a revision, they link to the most recent standing version of the doc.
Is this just how the Revision object works? How do I actually retrieve the content of a revision???

Comment: Let me investigate a bit more and I'll get back to you

Comment: This now should be fixed, you should be able to get exportLinks for each revision.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit and used this link:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list

in the items you have the links to the item.

I have also tried the
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get  and it works.

It returns the downloadUrl for the revision.